# Should I wrap the setting of a selection menu into a promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm generating some markup according to data I get from a database. 
This markup is then inserted into a dropdown menu ().

Generating this markup takes some time because lots of strings are concatenated. So far, at the end of this function, there is nothing returned because ultimately the markup is set as a "side-effect" of the function via `$('#someID').html(data)`.

Now, it is crucial that this function has finished its job before other functions are called. Therefore I would like to do all this stuff inside a promise and then return the variable holding the markup via "resolve". 
When it was returned, I would like to set the markup to the according element via `$('#someID').html(data)`  .

I'm just wondering whether this is a smart thing to do. Because I don't really know if there could by some timing-issue when the markup to be inserted into the select element is really big. Can the mere insertion of the markup, after it has been created already, take up a significant portion of time? Should I therefore wrap it into some promise as well? And if so, how can I do that? Because setting the markup to an HTML element doesn't really return anything.

To illustrate my explanation, here is some code to show what I'm currently aiming for:

```js
function createMarkup(dataFromDatabase){
  return new Promise (resolve => {
  var markup = //create the markup according to data from database
  resolve(markup)
  }
}

async function someStuff(data){
//some code
var markup = await createMarkup(data)
$('#someID').html(markup)
//some code which mustn't run before markup has been created and set to the
//according element
}
```

Comment: If `createMarkup()` is not actually asynchronous itself (e.g. it just concatenates a bunch of strings and doesn't call the database itself), then it's synchronous.  It will not return before it's done so there is no need or advantage to use a promise with it at all.   Just call the function and when it returns, it is done - normal Javascript programming, no promises.  The fact that an operation takes some time has nothing to do with whether you use a promise with it.  You use promises to monitor and coordinate ASYNCHRONOUS operations only.

Comment: wow, it works, thank you! :D